# How can I update working tree from index change that hasn't been committed yet?

Tags: git

You can't (without setting a .gitconfig setting) push to a repository unless it's a bare repository.

But I found that you can in fact do that, if all it's doing is a fast forward to the remote repository. Okay, makes sense.

So let's say non-bare repositories A and B are in sync and I make a change to A, add it, commit it to A, and then I git push B master

Git does this without complaint but what I end up with is the change going into B's index. Not the repository, and not the working tree.

I'm not sure I understand why it does that, but that aside for the moment, without committing, how can I pull the changes into B's working tree?

Checkout doesn't work because the change isn't in the repository yet, reset doesn't work for similar reasons. Merge, same thing.

When I say `git checkout master` it says `M <filename>`  of the file with the change but it doesn't actually merge anything.

`git merge` says `already up to date`.

So I'm a little lost here...

1. why does the push from A to B put the changes in the index, not
   the repository, and
2. how can I pull the changes (without committing first) from  B's
   index to B's working tree?

EDIT:
I'm playing some more, I made 2 new repositories to try this out and now it won't let me push because it says the other repository has that branch checked out.
But that's the same situation I have where it does let me push to the branch, it's the same master branch.

Comment: You shouldn't push to the _checked out_ branch of a working repo, but that's the only restriction on pushing to those.  Please post a command sequence that reproduces what you're describing here, starting from the init or clone creating both repos.  Almost none of it matches the behavior of the git I know.

Comment: I know I shouldn't and I also know it shouldn't let me, yet it does. Both repositories have only ever checked out 'master' so they should never be able to push to each other, but it does. But I think I figured out what was going on. I pushed from repo A to B and then when I git status from B what it's telling me is that the local changes don't match the repository, because I realized afterwards, the repository is ahead of the working tree. Usually I pull so it fetches and merges into the working tree, but obviously being pushed to it didn't update the working tree. Still two issues though:

Comment: 1) Why did it let me push to another repo that had master checked out, and 2) I could SWEAR that it said (git status from B) the changes were staged (as in, in the index) after the push to B, not merely unstaged changes.